# How to float until on left (or right) page?

Tags: floats, positioning, double-sided, rotating

I have two sideways tables that I want on two facing pages so the reader can turn the entire book and read them both in one turn. For the moment I keep moving them around to keep them on facing pages. Is there a way I can make the first one float until it's on a left page and then place the other one right after? Or perhaps some similar way to automatically get them on the same spread?

Comment: For reference: There's a [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-dpfloat.html) dedicated to this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use package `dpfloat` (double page float)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
\begin{leftfullpage}
This is the left side figure
\caption{And this is the caption of the left side figure}
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]% will be the right-side figure
\caption{And this is the caption of the right side figure}
\begin{fullpage}
This is the right side figure
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: FloatBarrier has no effect on these floats.

Comment: ?? Where did I wrote something about FloatBarrier??

Comment: You didn't I am just saying that if you want to use FloatBarrier to force all of the floats to be written prior to the start of the next section for example, it doesn't work if the floats are within the `leftfullpage` or `fullpage` environments. They run into the next section.

Comment: sure, what else do you expect when the floats are on a _full page_??

Comment: To fill blank counter-pages, or, write the 'leftfullpages' as 'fullpages' until all of the floats are written up until where the FloatBarrier is instructed.

Comment: insert a `\clearpage` at the beginning of the doublepage float and it should do what you expect. But then it is not a _real_ float and also not a good idea.

Comment: Hmmm, out of interest, why dont you think it is a good idea?

Comment: I wrote _not_ a good idea. If you do _not_ want something to float then do not use a floating environment.

Comment: I know you wrote NOT a good idea, that is why I asked why DON'T you think it is a good idea. I want things to float, just not into the next chapter, or into the bibliography, or into the appendixes for example.

Comment: oh, I should use my spectacles ... A float on an own page implies that a lot of text can be moved before that float. If you do not want that for a chapter and so on, then use `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` then the float is set first before the chapter starts.

Answer (score 6):

You may use package [afterpage](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to put something at the next page. Using this, you may define a new command, to put something onto the next even page:

```
\newcommand\atevenpage[1]{%
  \afterpage{\clearpage% be sure, that there are no pending floats
    \ifodd\value{page}% still a odd page
      \atevenpage{#1}%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi
  }%
}
```

Caveat: Sometimes `\afterpage` uses not exactly the next page but a later one. Because of this, I've not used `\afterpage` to delay output at odd pages, but one more `\atevenpage`. This may delay material a lot. And note, that you should not use `\afterpage` near to a `longtable`.

Comment: The `memoir` class and the `nextpage` package both have a `\cleartoevenpage` that can be used here.

Comment: @Karl: That's something completely different. `\cleartoevenpage` will set empty pages until next even page. `\atevenpage` will float the argument until next even page without adding empty pages into the document.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. I just noticed the (sometimes) double use of `\clearpage`, and thought you could use `\cleartoevenpage` instead, but of course you use a double `\afterpage` too, which makes all the difference.

Comment: Could this approach change the order of the floats?