# Fine Tuning Float Positioning

Tags: floats, positioning, double-sided

How can I make a float have a dedicated page AND be always placed on an EVEN page (ie left page of double sided book)?

I explicitly do not want to have certain floats taking up a whole page on the right hand side.

Comment: see linked qn (and dpfloat package) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35864/how-to-float-until-on-left-or-right-page?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. This question can probably get marked as duplicate.

Comment: I noticed that FloatBarrier doesn't work on the `dpfloat` controlled floats.