# How can I set two figures in landscape on a two-page spread?

Tags: floats, memoir, landscape, dpfloat

I'm trying to use `dpfloat` to set two figures on a two-page spread. Because the figures are rather wide, I would like to use `pdflscape` to set these pages in landscape. However, the following fails when `\begin{landscape}` is on an odd page:

```
...
% This fails iff on an odd page. If I add \cleartoevenpage here it works
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    ...
    \end{leftfullpage}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
      ...
    \end{fullpage}
  \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
...
```

When in the above example `\begin{landscape}` is on an even page (left page), then `dpfloat` behaves fine. If it begins on an odd page, `dpfloat` fails to float to an even page, and it reports

```
dpfloat moved a leftpage float from page 21.
```

100 times before crashing at the `\end{landscape}` line, perhaps because it is blocked by `landscape` (?). If I manually insert `\cleartoevenpage` before `\begin{landscape}` begins, it always works, however in that case I have blank paper before the float.

Here is a MWE that has similar but not identical symptoms. Instead of crashing when the landscape begins on an odd page, it floats to an even page but the page is not set in landscape.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Analysis}

\kant[3]

\section{Introduction}

\kant[4-7]
% \kant[8-12] % Uncomment this line to be on an odd page and make landscape fail

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{leftfullpage}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle(2, 1.2);  
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Box plot of number of positions sent per iteration using this scheme}
    \end{leftfullpage}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle(2,1.2);  
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Detailed plot.
      \emph{Top}: overview. \emph{Bottom}: nightly curve.
      \label{fig:overview}}
    \end{fullpage}
  \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

How can I set two figures in landscape on a two-page spread?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using the `afterpage` solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35866 works in this case. Although the solution passing the whole `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}` as argument to `\atevenpage` seems somewhat unsatisfactory, so I still wonder if there is a better solution.