# How to ensure two figures appear side by side on two pages?

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking

I am trying to make two figures (namely a map and its legend together with a long caption) appear side by side on separate pages.

So far, I have managed to put them on the next two available pages after their position in the code and let the text flow neatly around them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext}

\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[!hp]
        \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!hp]
        \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \caption{Caption}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

However, I do not know how to ensure those pages actually appear next to each other, i.e. how to ensure that figure A appears on the first *even* page following its position in the code.

In other words, how can I avoid results like this (produced with `\blindtext[5]` in the beginning):

[image]

Comment: Is this a one-off situation in your document, or does it occur several times?

Comment: Will there be something else on the second page, apart from the smaller image and the lenghty caption? I assume `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} \caption{Caption} \blindtext \end{minipage}` in your MWE resembles this long caption. Is that correct?

Comment: @IanThompson For my current situation it is only a one-time thing, so I could manually place the figure earlier/later in the document depending on the final length of the chapter, if that's what you are suggesting. But I thought it would be nice to have a *hooman stupid but machine smart, so it's ok*-solution to this and automate the process.

Comment: @leandriis The idea of using the ``minipage`` was to allow for the lower half of the second page to be 'designed' like normal text, e.g. for the insertion of references etc. But yes in this MWE it's only for that lengthy caption.

Comment: The following might be useful: [How to float until on left (or right) page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35864/134144)  and [Placing figure on an even/odd page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55653/134144)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?r=SearchResults&s=3|30.1801#281075

Comment: Yes, with just a one-off occurrence, I would have been lazy and moved the figures manually when everything else was finished. It looks like the solutions suggested by @leandriis are a lot better than that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to leandriis I found the solution I was looking for in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35869/163512) and even [a TeXFAQ page](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-dpfloat.html).

For reference, here is the adaptation of my MWE using the `dpfloat` package and its `leftfullpage` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx,blindtext}
\usepackage{dpfloat}

\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[5]
    \begin{figure}[!hp]
        \begin{leftfullpage}
        \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!hp]
        \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \caption{Caption}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]